# Read a character from an x-y coordinate on the screen

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Is there a way in bash to read a character from an x-y coordinate on the screen? This command would be something similar to

```
cget 12 30
```

which would return the character at the 12th row and 30th column.

Comment: From a terminal? Which one? Some (`screen`, Linux virtual console, for instance) let you query that information, some don't

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the console ttys (`/dev/tty1` through `/dev/tty7`) in text mode you can read the screen buffer directly from the corresponding `/dev/vcsN` device.

Since you shouldn't really assume there are 80 characters per line, it's necessary to ask the terminal display its characters per line. Then simple maths will convert an (x,y) coordinate to offset (y*c + x) will get you the desired character:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
my_tty=$(tty)
vcs_nr="${my_tty/*tty/}"

# Read Y, X from first two characters of /dev/vcsaN (we only use X)
xwidth=$(
    dd if="/dev/vcsa$vcs_nr" bs=1c count=2 2>/dev/null |
    od -t u1 -A d |
    awk '{print $3; exit}'
)

# Calculate byte offset into the screen
offset=$(( ($2 -1) * xwidth + ($1 -1) ))

# Read the data
dd count=1 skip="$offset" bs=1 if="/dev/vcs$vcs_nr" 2>/dev/null
```

This presupposes root access to the /dev/vcsN devices, of course.

Comment: There aren't necessarily 80 cols per line. Use `stty size` to find out how many.

Comment: Also note that while it will work for ASCII characters, for other characters, you'll probably need to use  the output `setfont -ou /dev/stdout` to map those byte values back to actually characters.

Comment: (note that consoles are not limited to /dev/tty1..tty7, the current max number is 63)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I use tput to get the number of rows and columns. Thanks though.

Comment: @user973810, yes, on Linux where `tput` would be likely coming from `ncurses`, `tput cols` would work as well in the same way as `stty size`, that is, it retrieves the size as recorded by the tty device which for Linux virtual consoles should always be accurate. The only reason it wouldn't work is if somehow `$TERM` is not known in the terminfo database (even though `tput cols` doesn't need to query that database) which should normally not happen.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: It’s also possible to open vcs **a** and read first two bytes from it.

Comment: For me `$MY_TTY` is undefined???

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix ah, thank you. It was a typo introduced during an earlier refactoring. I've changed the top two lines to fix this.