# How to copy from CLI without a GUI or a mouse

Tags: command-line

In *nix, if I **don't have a mouse**, nor am I running a GUI, what can I do to copy from what is on the screen?

**Take this for example:**

[image]

What if I want to copy things from **"Entering /mnt/..."** to **the last "}"**

Thanks for the answer
[Read a character from an x-y coordinate on the screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181145/read-a-character-from-an-x-y-coordinate-on-the-screen)
But something unique on Chromebook is that I only have `/dev/tty` and `/dev/tty8`. And I don't have `/dev/vcsN` what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read a character from an x-y coordinate on the screen](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181145/read-a-character-from-an-x-y-coordinate-on-the-screen)

Comment: Where do you want to be able to "paste" the text?

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks but I only have `/dev/tty` and `/dev/tty8`. And I don't have `/dev/vcsN` what should I do?

Comment: @StephenKitt maybe into a text file or something or just to google when there is a problem.

Comment: try `sudo enter-chroot | tee temp_file.txt`, then you could `scp` the `temp_file.txt`. I think `tee` would still allow you to enter the password at the prompt.

Comment: @the_velour_fog That's a good way but can I do it outside chroot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In such circumstances, [`script`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) is very handy: it runs a shell, recording all the output. In your example, before entering the chroot you'd run

```
script temp_file.txt
```

and then

```
sudo enter-chroot
```

etc. On exit from the chroot, you'd exit again to exit `script`, and you'd find the text you wanted (along with everything else you did) in `temp_file.txt`.

Another possibility is to run your session within [`screen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html); that allows both saving the current "window" (in `screen` parlance) to a file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>h</kbd> by default; this dumps the contents of the screen to a file named `hardcopy.n` where `n` is a counter) and copying and pasting between windows (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd> by default will enter scrollback/copy mode; see the documentation for details).

Comment: that's a very good way but I found that in `temp_file.txt` there are lots of things...like `]0;chronos@localhost:~/Downloads[01;32mchronos@localhost[01;34m ~/Downloads $[00m ls` which makes it hard to read

Comment: You can strip the ANSI escapes from the file to make it easier to read; see http://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream for details.

Answer (score 2):

Get into the habit of working in [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) (or [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) which has roughly the same set of features). Screen provides a terminal in a terminal with several advantages; the most commonly useful one is that you can detach and reattach to a Screen terminal but the one you want is that Screen maintains a configurable amount of scrollback history and you can copy the text from it.

To select part of the displayed text or scrollback history and copy it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>. You are now in [copy/scrollback mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Copy). Press arrow keys to move, <kbd>Space</kbd> to start selecting, move some more and press and <kbd>Space</kbd> again to copy. To paste the text into the Screen window, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>. To paste into a file, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>></kbd>.